# Bash script to rename file to just the date substring in the filename

Tags: bash, substring

I have a list of files from the beginning of June till today that have arbitrary names with the date in them.

They are:

```
JUNE 13.pdf

JUNE 16 MIDTERM REVIEW LAND GRABS 1 EXCLUSION AND BACKGROUND,.pdf

LECTURE JUNE 21 RUBBER RIGHTS RESISTANCE.pdf

SUMMER JUNE 15 TITLING AND LEGIBILITY.pdf

SUMMER JUNE 22 LIVELIHOODS.pdf

summer JUN 14 PROPERTY RIGHTS LECTURE.pdf
```

I have been trying for quite a while today to get the hang of bash but in all the solutions I've looked at have really complicated syntax that I don't understand. I know you can extract the date from the file and name it accordingly, but I really want to learn how to extract substrings using bash.

The best solution I've come up with has been found from [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html)

```
for j in *.pdf;
do
  length=`expr match "$j" 'JUN[E, ] ??'`
  ind=`expr index "$j" 'JUN' `
  mv $j ${j:ind:length}
done
```

but this solution just gives me many syntax errors without any indication of what I'm doing wrong. I've also tried using cut, rename, some other "standard" stuff but I'm really struggling.

Comment: Would you be willing to use Python or some other, more powerful language?

Comment: If it's an executable shell command then yeah I guess.

Comment: `expr match` is an anchored match: it will only match the start of a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`expr` is useful, but probably not the easiest way to do this.  (The `match` command will only match at the start of the string.)  I am assuming that you are getting the date to match a directory: change the test as needed if that is an incorrect assumption.  Try sed:

```
for i in *.pdf; do 
  d=$(echo "$i" | sed -E 's/.*(JUNE? [0-9]+).*/\1/'); 
  test -d "$d" && mv -i "$i" "$d" 
done
```

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. The only issue is that it doesn't automatically rename JUN to JUNE.

Comment: Also, it removed the .pdf from the files which I didn't notice, but I appended them back.

Comment: To replace JUN with JUNE, you could use `sed -E 's/.*JUNE? *([0-9]+).*/JUNE \1/'`

Answer (score 1):

I'd use Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import re
import sys

regex = re.compile('.*(JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUNE?|JULY?|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC) (\d+).*(\.\w+)$')

for filename in sys.argv[1:]:
    matches = regex.match(filename)
    if matches:
        newname = ''.join(matches.groups())
        print "rename -", filename, "- to -", newname
        #os.rename(filename, newname)
```

Uncomment the last line once you've tested it and seen the printed results are what you want.

Comment: This is a good answer, it pointed me towards a more powerful toolbox that I didn't know about, but I'm going to have to read up on some of that syntax tomorrow to understand it.